# Return associated probability for samples from tf.multinomial in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm generating samples in Tensorflow with [tf.multinomial](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multinomial), and I'm looking for a way to return associated probability with the randomly selected element. So in the following case:

```
logits = [[-1., 0., 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
samples = tf.multinomial(logits, 2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(samples)
```

Instead of having

```
[[1, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

as result, I'd like to see something like

```
[[(1, 0.244728), (2, 0.66524)], 
 [(0, 0.33333), (1, 0.33333)], 
 [(1, 0.244728), (1, 0.244728)]]
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused , does tensorflow do some sort of transformation on the inside that turns your logits into probabilities? The multinomial distribution takes in as parameters a set of positional probabilities that determines, probabilistically the likelihood of the outcome (positionally) being sampled. i.e

```
# this is all psuedocode
x = multinomial([.2, .3, .5])
y ~ x
# this will give a value of 0 20% of the time
# a value of 1 30% of the time
# and a value of 2 50% of the time
```

therefor your probabilities might be your logits.

looking at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multinomial

you see it states they are "unnormalized log probabilities" so if you can apply that transformation, you have the probabilities

Comment: `tf.multinomial(logits, 1)` will return a value within `[0, 3)`, so the OP wants to get the corresponding probability, for example, if the logits are `[0.6, 0.3, 0.1]`, the sampled idx is 0, the probability is 0.6

Answer (score 0):

You can try `tf.gather_nd`, you can try

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.enable_eager_execution()
>>> probs = tf.constant([[0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2], [0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]], dtype=tf.float32)
>>> idx = tf.multinomial(probs, 1)
>>> row_indices = tf.range(probs.get_shape()[0], dtype=tf.int64)
>>> full_indices = tf.stack([row_indices, tf.squeeze(idx)], axis=1)
>>> rs = tf.gather_nd(probs, full_indices)
```

Or, you can use [`tf.distributions.Multinomial`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Multinomial), the advantage is you do not need to care about the `batch_size` in the above code. It works under varying `batch_size` when you set the `batch_size=None`. Here is a simple example,

```
multinomail = tf.distributions.Multinomial(
                         total_count=tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32),
                         probs=probs)
sampled_actions = multinomail.sample()  # sample one action for data in the batch
predicted_actions = tf.argmax(sampled_actions, axis=-1) 
action_probs = sampled_actions * predicted_probs 
action_probs = tf.reduce_sum(action_probs, axis=-1)
```

I think this is what you want to do. I prefer the latter one because it is flexible and elegant.